# SetSelected not called on unlock after a long time (~1 hr), credential tile not refreshed (Windows 8.1)

Tags: authentication, winapi, windows-8.1, credential-providers

**Background** -
We have developed a custom credential provider that wraps Windows credential provider to provide 2-FA. We are facing an issue specific to Windows 8.1.

**Scenario** -
Using our code, windows users have two screens during machine login - our custom tile that authenticates a user (by our custom mechanism) followed by the windows tile that authenticates using user's AD credential. 
We have a feature of bypassing our custom authentication upon unlock within x hours (i.e. if a user locks & unlocks their machine within x hrs, 2-FA will be skipped) - the logic to decide which is implemented in a function called from within ICredentialProviderCredential::SetSelected.

**What is happening?** - 
Ideally windows call SetSelected function whenever a credential tile loads - during both login and unlock scenario. However, in windows 8.1, if the machine is left idle in the locked state for about an hour, the next time user tries to authenticate the credential tile loads maintaining the previous state, not calling SetSelected function for the tile to reload. Due to which our validation logic for whether or not 2-FA should be skipped is not executing upon unlock.

*Expected behavior* - In windows lock scenario after ~1 hr, windows should call SetSelected function.
*Observed behavior* - In windows lock scenario after ~1 hr, SetSelected function is not executed.

**Troubleshooting** - 
If we lock the machine, the tile loaded initially on the lock screen is correct and as expected because SetSelected function is called. However if we keep it idle for an hour, the tile is not reloaded again calling the SetSelected function but it retaining the tile which was earlier loaded.

We have verified the same on Windows 7 & 10, and we get the expected behavior with the same implementation. Is there something specific to Windows 8.1 - its behavior or functionality that could explain why the credential tile is not reloaded every time after the machine is left idle?

Comment: *the logic to decide which is implemented in a function called from within ICredentialProviderCredential::SetSelected* think you must not do this here, but change general logic

Comment: I have implemented my own 2FA logic inside of `ICredentialProviderCredential::GetSerialization` method and it is works fine for ages.

Comment: @Alexander we are also changing the UI depending on what type of authentication we want - our custom based or windows authentication, which is why we can't keep the deciding logic in GetSerialization because by then the UI is already loaded.

Comment: @Ipsha you can create two tiles for one user - one for 2FA, another for windows credentials. User will choose which of them use if they both available. Moreover you can change the tiles and their count calling to `ICredentialProviderEvents::CredentialsChanged`.

Comment: @Alexander yes, that can be done. However, this is not our use-case. We don't want to provide the user an option of selecting between tiles - it would defeat our purpose of enforcing 2FA if they could simply select the other tile and login via Windows credential only.